# Is there a numerical method to solve a triple integral without numeric limits in its inner integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

Let's say I have this triple integral with this kind of limits:

$$
\int _0^2\:\int_x^{8x}\:\int _0^y4xyz\:dz\:dy\:dx\:
$$

I wondering what numerical method I can use to solve it and eventually write a program/script to solve it. No symbolic solutions, no python+sympy.

Thanks.

Note: No need to solve it, just the right numeric method to solve this kind of integrals.

Comment: python + scipy?

Comment: That's the second part! I need to be able to do it myself with a numeric method, then the computer.

Comment: The question is not clearly delimited / defined for my taste. What does it mean "numerically solve" or the "right numeric method" for (a) an integral with one variable and with fixed limits, (b) for the above integral (on a compact domain in $\Bbb R^3$)? Why is the usual approach to solve integral after integral after integral, each integral numerically computed "with usual algorithms", not applicable?

Comment: Well then the answer might be just easier. What algorithm can I use without using a symbolic library? I can't just code a regular algorithm with those limits.

Comment: Simple algorithm (though not the best) to implement here is [Monte Carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration). Make $n$ samples $\{x,y,z\}_i$ where you draw uniformly $x\in[0,2]$ and $y,z\in[0,16]$. Sum up $4xyz$ for the samples that satisfy $z<y$ and $x<y<8x$. Your integral is then this sum times $(16\cdot 16\cdot 2)/n$. The answer to $1\%$ with $10^6$ samples.

Comment: @Winther very interesting method. I'll try it thanks!

Comment: @Winther I'm just getting into numerical methods. What would be a "not so bad" algorithm? only non deterministic methods work in this case? I already coded simpsons, trapezoidal and so...

Comment: No, standard methods like trapezoidal and simpsons work just fine. But the higher the dimension the more expensive they are.